Iterate through Array- Free marker language
I would like to iterate through array and return output
Input :
[
{
"Id": "246539",
"Name": "MyName1",
"type": "Student"
},
{
"Id": "246536",
"Name": "MyName1",
"type": "Faculty"
}
]
expected output :
{
"hierarchyNode1": {
"facultyDetails": [
{
"Id": "246539",
"data": {
"Id": "246539",
"Name": "MyName1",
"type": "2"
}
},
{
"Id": "246536",
"data": {
"Id": "246536",
"Name": "MyName2",
"type": "4"
}
}
]
}
}
Not able to parse with below script :
    <#assign jsonObjects = []> <#list payload as item><#assign jsonObject = { "identifier": item.Id,
"fullName": item.Name,
"roleType": item.type}><#assign jsonObjects += [jsonObject]></#list>

TIA
